# jQuery Steps Basic Example places body in wrong location

Tags: jquery-steps

I'm trying to get the jQuery Steps [Basic Example](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic) working from the documentation, but it places the bodyTag section to the right of Steps rather than underneath. Any idea why?

Everything loads okay, and there's no Console errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Steps Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/jquery.steps.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>    

    <div id="example-basic">
        <h3>Keyboard</h3>
        <section>
            <p>Try the keyboard navigation by clicking arrow left or right!</p>
        </section>
        <h3>Effects</h3>
        <section>
            <p>Wonderful transition effects.</p>
        </section>
        <h3>Pager</h3>
        <section>
            <p>The next and previous buttons help you to navigate through your content.</p>
        </section>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $("#example-basic").steps({
                headerTag: "h3",
                bodyTag: "section",
                transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
                autoFocus: true
            });
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to play a little with the custom CSS that library comes with. You only need to modify `.wizard > .content` by setting `display: inline-block;` and `width: 100%;`, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#example-basic").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    autoFocus: true
  });
})
```

```css
/*
    Common 
*/

.wizard,
.tabcontrol
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wizard a,
.tabcontrol a
{
    outline: 0;
}

.wizard ul,
.tabcontrol ul
{
    list-style: none !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wizard ul > li,
.tabcontrol ul > li
{
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Accessibility */
.wizard > .steps .current-info,
.tabcontrol > .steps .current-info
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
}

.wizard > .content > .title,
.tabcontrol > .content > .title
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
}



/*
    Wizard
*/

.wizard > .steps
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.wizard.vertical > .steps
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}

.wizard > .steps .number
{
    font-size: 1.429em;
}

.wizard > .steps > ul > li
{
    width: 25%;
}

.wizard > .steps > ul > li,
.wizard > .actions > ul > li
{
    float: left;
}

.wizard.vertical > .steps > ul > li
{
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.wizard > .steps a,
.wizard > .steps a:hover,
.wizard > .steps a:active
{
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard > .steps .disabled a,
.wizard > .steps .disabled a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .disabled a:active
{
    background: #eee;
    color: #aaa;
    cursor: default;
}

.wizard > .steps .current a,
.wizard > .steps .current a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .current a:active
{
    background: #2184be;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: default;
}

.wizard > .steps .done a,
.wizard > .steps .done a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .done a:active
{
    background: #9dc8e2;
    color: #fff;
}

.wizard > .steps .error a,
.wizard > .steps .error a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .error a:active
{
    background: #ff3111;
    color: #fff;
}

.wizard > .content
{
    background: #eee;
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5em;
    min-height: 35em;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard.vertical > .content
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2.5% 0.5em 2.5%;
    width: 65%;
}

.wizard > .content > .body
{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 2.5%;
}

.wizard > .content > .body ul
{
    list-style: disc !important;
}

.wizard > .content > .body ul > li
{
    display: list-item;
}

.wizard > .content > .body > iframe
{
    border: 0 none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wizard > .content > .body input
{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.wizard > .content > .body input[type="checkbox"]
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.wizard > .content > .body input.error
{
    background: rgb(251, 227, 228);
    border: 1px solid #fbc2c4;
    color: #8a1f11;
}

.wizard > .content > .body label
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.wizard > .content > .body label.error
{
    color: #8a1f11;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.wizard > .actions
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}

.wizard.vertical > .actions
{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 2.5%;
    width: 95%;
}

.wizard > .actions > ul
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}

.wizard > .actions > ul > li
{
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.wizard.vertical > .actions > ul > li
{
    margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}

.wizard > .actions a,
.wizard > .actions a:hover,
.wizard > .actions a:active
{
    background: #2184be;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard > .actions .disabled a,
.wizard > .actions .disabled a:hover,
.wizard > .actions .disabled a:active
{
    background: #eee;
    color: #aaa;
}

.wizard > .loading
{
}

.wizard > .loading .spinner
{
}



/*
    Tabcontrol
*/

.tabcontrol > .steps
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 6px 0 0 0;
    top: 1px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li
{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 2px 0 0;
    padding: 1px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li:hover
{
    background: #edecec;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding: 0;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li.current
{
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    padding: 0 0 1px 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li > a
{
    color: #5f5f5f;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li > a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li.current > a
{
    padding: 15px 30px 10px 30px;
}

.tabcontrol > .content
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35em;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.tabcontrol > .content > .body
{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 2.5%;
}

.tabcontrol > .content > .body ul
{
    list-style: disc !important;
}

.tabcontrol > .content > .body ul > li
{
    display: list-item;
}
.wizard > .content{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-steps/1.1.0/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
<div id="example-basic">
  <h3>Keyboard</h3>
  <section>
    <p>Try the keyboard navigation by clicking arrow left or right!</p>
  </section>
  <h3>Effects</h3>
  <section>
    <p>Wonderful transition effects.</p>
  </section>
  <h3>Pager</h3>
  <section>
    <p>The next and previous buttons help you to navigate through your content.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!.If only this was in the documentation!

Comment: I noticed there's also a working CSS fix here, but yours is much simpler: https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/issues/6

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. Please accept the answer if you think it fits your needs. Thank you.